# JobDSL - No signature of method java.lang.String

Tags: jenkins, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

I have the following code to build as a job-dsl with "Active Choice Plugin":

```
freeStyleJob('job') {


description('description')

// Label which specifies on which nodes this job can be run.
label('master')

logRotator {
    numToKeep(10)
}

//This Build is parametrized
parameters {
    activeChoiceReactiveParam('branch') {
        description('Select the branch you are going to use')
        choiceType('SINGLE_SELECT')
        script('["integration", "master"]')
        fallbackScript('"Error. No branch to select."')
        filterable(true)
    }

}
}
```

I when executing it I get the following error:

[image]

How can this error be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is actually a bit different:

```
job('example-1') {
  parameters {
    activeChoiceReactiveParam('CHOICE-1') {
      description('Allows user choose from multiple choices')
      filterable()
      choiceType('SINGLE_SELECT')
      groovyScript {
        script('["choice1", "choice2"]')
        fallbackScript('"fallback choice"')
      }
      referencedParameter('BOOLEAN-PARAM-1')
      referencedParameter('BOOLEAN-PARAM-2')
    }
  }
}
```

Use the API viewer to lookup the syntax:
https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-parameters-activeChoiceReactiveParam

Comment: I forgot to add "groovyScript" code block... what a mistake... Thank you @daskilker !